# Synchronising parallel processes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, monads

In Haskell, how can I run multiple (monad?) functions (such as `print`) in parallel and see their output in the order of their finish time? I want three processes each one ending up in a print function.

```
import Control.Parallel
main = a `par` b `pseq` (a,b)
    where
        a = print("ack",ack 3 10)
        b = print("fac",fac 42)
```

If I don't use `pseq`, it will show the last one specified in `par` combination. I want to make sure all processes are finished before the program ends. I tried this but it does not show the output of a,b:

```
...
main = a `par` b `pseq` print("done.")
...
```

Note: my program ends with the following lines:

```
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)
ack 0 n = n+1
ack m 0 = ack (m-1) 1
ack m n = ack (m-1) (ack m (n-1))
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `Control.Parallel` for running IO actions concurrently.

[`Control.Concurrent.Async`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:mapConcurrently) should do what you want – `Control.Parallel` is used for hinting which pure operations can be evaluated simultaneously, not for running multiple actions (monadic or otherwise) at the same time.

Comment: Is there any way of combining the print monads (like `a+b+c` ) to make the combined one work with `Control.Parallel` ?

Comment: no, because that's not what `Control.Parallel` is for (telling the compiler "hey, if you can calculate both these results at the same time, work them out together because you'll get the full answer faster"), `Async` is for saying "do this at the same time as this other thing".

Answer (score 1):

In the C family of languages, there's a difference between these 2 lines

```
a = foobar; // This just sets a to be a function pointer to foobar
b = foobar(); // This actually runs foobar and stores the result in `b`
```

Your code basically has the same problem as if you were writing C and forgot the `()` at the end of all your function calls. It assigns the function pointers `a` and `b` in parallel but doesn't actually call them.

If you are writing pure functions in Haskell, you can add parallelism using `par`, but it doesn't work for `IO` because `IO a` is like a function pointer. Your code "evaluates" `a` and `b` in parallel but the result of that evaluation is still waiting for you to actually execute it.

For code that lives in `IO`, you have to import `Control.Concurrent` and use the function `forkIO` to create the new thread. Then because the child threads all automatically die when the main thread finishes, you need some way of making the main thread wait (I'll use `MVar`s in the example because they're the simplest reliable way to do it)

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = do
  -- MVars have a type parameter because you can also use them to send data
  -- between threads, but in this example I'm basically just using them as locks
  await <- newEmptyMVar :: IO (MVar ())
  bwait <- newEmptyMVar :: IO (MVar ())
  forkIO $ print ("ack",ack 3 10) >> putMVar await ()
  forkIO $ print ("fac",fac 42) >> putMVar bwait ()
  takeMVar await
  takeMVar bwait
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer.